# How Do I list all the controls inside one UIViewcontroller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm used to .net UI, and I am used to go inside the array of controls inside one container,

I am wondering about ui in cocoa-touch I can do the same, once I didn't find it out there

thanks

Comment: If you want to see all the actions/outlets a VC can have, simply click on the view controller in the storyboard or xib file, and go to the last Utility on the right (the connections inspector). It will show you outlets, segues and actions.

Comment: what I mean is to list the collection of controls from one particular container, in this case, just to illustrate, a uiviewcontroller

Comment: Assuming u have added the controllers using the method - (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController; . You can access using viewController.childViewControllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by enumerating the subviews of that container view recursively, checking if they are subclasses of UIControl and adding them to an array.
You could create a similar category to UIView(this code is completely untested)

```
- (NSArray*)containedControls
{
    NSMutableArray *controls = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(UIView *subview in self.subviews){
        if([subview isSubclassOfClass:[UIControl class]])
            [controls appendObject:subview]
        else {
            NSArray *containedInSubview = [subview containedControls];
            [controls addObjectsFromArray:containedInSubview];
        }
    }

    return controls;
}
```